# Design for extending react native webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I want to create a wrapper around react-native webview such that I provide some of the default values and client can override them. I would also like to provide default implementations for methods

For Example:

```
<MyBaseWebView uri ={provided by user of MyBaseWebView}>
MyBaseWebView can have default implementations for onError etc.
```

I have been using props to send various overrides from client but I am what to do for the following:

- `ref={this.setRNWebView}` This needs to be only in one of the children
- `injectedJavaScript={this.injectedJavaScript()}` I don't want to inject any javascript at all  if client does not send it. How can I achieve this?

The BaseWebView class looks like the following:

```
<WebView
  allowsInlineMediaPlayback={this.allowsInlineMediaPlayback()}
  ref={this.setRNWebView}
  source={{uri: uri}} // from prop
  mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={this.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction()}
  onMessage={this.onMessage}
  onError={this.onError}
  onLoad={this.onLoad}
  injectedJavaScript={this.injectedJavaScript()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to add `state` variables, probably on the screen thats before the webview.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uri: "www.defaultUri.com",
      injectedJavascript: "", 
    };
  }

//then for example in a textInput in render() you could allow your 
//user to update these values

<TextInput
value={this.state.uri}
onChangeText={text => this.setState({uri: text})}/>
```

You can do the same for `injectedJavascript` or any other variable and when your user hits submit or something you can pass those state variables to your `webview` as props.

Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for or not clear enough.